# Кросс-валидация в Python

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение

Нужно получить кросс-валидацию на трёх равных по размеру блоках. Делаю так и получаю ошибку "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead":

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

data = pd.read_csv('/datasets/heart.csv')
features = data.drop(['target'], axis=1)
target = data['target']

scores = []

sample_size = int(len(data)/3)

for i in range(0, len(data), sample_size):
    valid_indexes = data.iloc[i: i + sample_size].index
    train_indexes = (data.iloc[:i] + data.iloc[i + sample_size:]).index

    features_train = features.iloc[train_indexes]
    features_valid = features.iloc[valid_indexes]
    target_train = target.iloc[train_indexes]
    target_valid = target.iloc[valid_indexes]
    
    model = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
    model = model.fit(features_train, target_train)
    score = model.score(target_valid, features_valid)
    
    scores.append(score)
 
final_score = score.mean()  
print('Средняя оценка качества модели:', final_score)

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1.
 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.
```

Comment: 25 строка, перепутаны местами аргументы метода score, и среднее посчитал как ```final_score = sum(scores) / len(scores)```

Comment: А вот это вот про что: "array=[0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0......" может какой разделитель между значениями вставить, запятую например (согласно правилам синтаксиса Python)? Ну и неплохо бы сообщать, при выполнении какой именно команды произошла ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка объясняется тем, что перепутаны местами аргументы при вызове метода `score`, правильно будет так:

```py
score = model.score(features_valid, target_valid)
```

`features_valid` - двумерный массив
`target_valid` - одномерный массив

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]